# What is the cut-off for quantum superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

Is there an explanation as to how macro objects aren't in superposition? At what size do objects stop being in a state of superposition?

Comment: What makes you think "macro" objects are not in superposition? How do you define a "macro" object in contrast to a "micro" object? Do you understand that states can be a single eigenstate w.r.t. to one observable and in a "superposition" (I hate that word) of eigenstates w.r.t to another observable?

Comment: @ACuriousMind well I think that because I only see it referred to quantum onjects. And I'm pretty sure unobserved large objects aren't in multiple states.

Answer (score 5):

There are many models that attempt to explain this quantum-to-classical transition, but the main idea behind most of them is something called decoherence.  I'm not an expert on the subject (yet!), so I won't try to elaborate further but you can get started [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence). For a more complete treatment of quantum measurement and decoherence check out [Wiseman & Milburn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521804426), it's pretty good.

What I can tell you though, is that **there is no known "boundary" that divides the quantum and classical worlds**, and under highly controlled conditions in labs, larger and larger objects are being put in relatively 'clean' quantum states. In [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v478/n7367/full/nature10461.html) work a silicon chip roughly the size of a red blood cell, consisting of millions of atoms, was cooled to its vibrational quantum ground state. In a later paper this group indirectly detected the zero-point motion of the oscillator, showing that the object really was in a non-classical state! Of course, this object is still quite small, but it is *massive* compared to textbook quantum systems like atoms and molecules.

So to answer your question, so far all the evidence seems to indicate that putting full-out macroscopic objects in a quantum state is possible *in principle*.

Answer (score 0):

A quantum stops being in a superposition of different eigenstates for a certain observable until it is measured. After the measurement it is in a certain eigenstate.

If an quantum interacts with its environment and gives information about its state to the environment this is already a "measurement".

A certain border for a size of object for which superpositions of states can exist can not be drawn.

Comment: I don't get what you stated in that second paragraph @http8000 are you saying that it measures itself? How can this be if we have to measure the quantum particles for it to be in a specific state?

Comment: @user50282: Is it more clear if I say "If the environment interacts with the quantum..." One needs somehow to clarify what is a "measurement". You can have a look a chapers 5.4 and 5.6 for a more detailed discussion (http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0609163).