# Is there a limit of size for superpositions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, superposition, decoherence

Can objects be always in superposition if there were no environment for decoherence to occur.

Comment: possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122088/291677

Comment: Thanks! What would a mechanism be for example if superpositions weren't allow for more massive set of particles? What would create that switch?

Comment: You have to make one up! For example, add some terms to the Schroedinger equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_spontaneous_localization_model

Comment: Yes I've heard of the model, however, isn't unitarity kind of important?

Comment: Of course it's important, as is matching classical/macroscopic predictions. But most important is matching experimental evidence, so all theories must be scrutinized accordingly

Comment: Any state $\left | \psi \right >$ is a superposition of $\left ( \left | \psi \right > \pm \left | \psi^\prime \right > \right ) / \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the laws of quantum mechanics, certainly. However, this assumes the system is still completely isolated - even the presence of a gravitational source can lead to decoherence, as per [this article](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys3366), because the objects might be in superpositions of two different gravitational potentials. As well, it assumes that the laws of quantum mechanics hold for macroscopic objects (that's why people keep trying to push quantum mechanics experiments to larger and more massive systems, to test this assumption).

Comment: And for example, what happens to the other values of the wavefunction?